# Getting value from other function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have html5 score base game. when game over, end screen shows total score via the below function:

```
this.show = function (a)
{
    b.text = TEXT_GAMEOVER;
    e.text = TEXT_SCORE + ": " + a;
    d.visible = !0;
};
```

Now i want to get total score that is `a` or `e.text` in the onclick button release function:

```
var a;
this._onButSendRelease = function ()
{ 
       console.log(a);
}
```

but `a` is undefined, Please help me how i can do that.

Comment: `function (a)` will create a new local variable `a` and will not change your exisitng `a` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store your score in a variable declared in the *global* scope :

```
var score; //Declare your variable here

this.show = function (a)
{
    b.text = TEXT_GAMEOVER;
    e.text = TEXT_SCORE + ": " + a;
    score = a; //Populate your variable here
    d.visible = !0;
};

this._onButSendRelease = function ()
{
    console.log(score); //Display your variable here
}
```

Comment: i tried this but i'm getting this in console a {_listeners: null, _captureListeners: null, alpha: 1, cacheCanvas: null, cacheID: 0, …}